# C++ CLI Missing ';' before '}'

Tags: c++-cli

I am learning C++/CLI and attempting to build an Interop component for my C# project.  I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it?  Any ideas?

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace Firewall {

    public ref class Firewall
    {
        void StartFirewall(){};
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't C++. I take it it is supposed to be Microsoft's .NET version.

Comment: @Neil: Yes, it's called C++/CLI, as it says in the title.

Comment: @BlueRaha You mean the title I just edited?

Comment: @Neil: Apologies, my mistake :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unlike C#, C++ requires a semicolon after a type definition.

```
public ref class Firewall
{
    void StartFirewall(){} // doesn't require semicolon here
}; // needs semicolon here.
```

<sub>In C#, you *can* actually have semicolons after type definitions (not recommended though) and that will be ignored. It is there for the sake of consistency with C++ syntax.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to have the `;` in the place you currently have it.  Instead place it after the closing `}` of the class `Firewall`.

```
public ref class Firewall
{
    void StartFirewall(){}
};
```